# Mysql Query doesn't work as expected (with left joins)

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello mysql and sql experts

I have a problem with my query.

I have 3 tables (As you can see in the images below)

One table for the event
One table for the user account
And one table where the event table and user account table is linked to (Teilnehmer table)

When a user Sign up to a event, the EventID and also the UserID will be stored in the Teilnehmer table.

That works fine.

Now the problem is, I've created a query which should only return the events, which are Enabled = 1, the user didn't Sign up to and the Count of FK_eventID is < Event.Anzahl

but that doesn't work.

The Count and Enabled join works, but although the user sign up to a event, the event will still be returned

can anybody see my problem ?

```
SELECT v.ID, 
       v.NameVeranstaltung, 
       v.Datum, 
       v.Uhrzeit, 
       v.Anzahl, 
       v.Beschreibung, 
       v.Enabled, 
       Count(t.FK_eventID) 
FROM   Veranstaltung AS v 
       LEFT JOIN Teilnehmer AS t 
              ON t.FK_eventID = v.ID 
       LEFT JOIN Users AS u 
              ON t.FK_userID = 17 
WHERE  v.Enabled = 1 
GROUP  BY t.FK_eventID, 
          v.NameVeranstaltung 
HAVING Count(t.FK_eventID) < v.Anzahl
```

[image][[image]][[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQEtJ.png)[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). And most people here dont speak german

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may solved your problem.

I used sub-querys for your "problem"

Use this code

```
SELECT 
          v.ID, v.NameVeranstaltung, v.Datum, v.Uhrzeit, v.Anzahl, v.Beschreibung, v.Enabled
          FROM
            Veranstaltung as v 
          WHERE 
            v.Enabled=1 and
            not exists
            (
              SELECT 1
              FROM Teilnehmer as t
              WHERE t.FK_eventID=v.ID and t.FK_userID = '$uid'
            )
            and v.Anzahl >
            (
              SELECT count(*)
              FROM Teilnehmer as t
              WHERE t.FK_eventID=v.ID
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use OUTER JOIN so that it would include events that don't have associated user on the right side and then add the condition that user_id is null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add condition that give me all those events which `enabled` but user has not signed up for it as follows. Also allow `JOIN` to happen in its purest form as described below.

You are missing this condition in your query

```
AND v.ID <> t.FK_eventID
```

Complete query should be,

```
    SELECT v.ID, 
       v.NameVeranstaltung, 
       v.Datum, 
       v.Uhrzeit, 
       v.Anzahl, 
       v.Beschreibung, 
       v.Enabled, 
       Count(t.FK_eventID) 
FROM   Veranstaltung AS v   
WHERE  v.Enabled = 1 AND v.ID NOT IN (
              SELECT t.FK_eventID 
              FROM Teilnehmer AS t LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON t.FK_userID = u.ID
              HAVING Count(t.FK_eventID) < v.Anzahl) 
GROUP  v.NameVeranstaltung
```

You should not be doing this,

```
left join Users as u on t.FK_userID=17
```

Instead allow JOIN to happen in its pure form and define your additional criteria in `WHERE` clause as follows,

```
left join Users as u on t.FK_userID=u.ID where v.Enabled=1 and u.ID = 17
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
But the problem is, I want to show all events which the user doesn't sign u to.
With your query it shows me the Events which the user sign up to

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger I have updated my answer. Please try updated query

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is still the same, it shows me the events which the user signed up to and not the events which the user didn't sign up to.

I uploaded the export of the db on OneDrive maybe you can try your query and see why it doesn't work
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AisM5-_Hn06SgYQKrbwYWR75OJlAyw

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger I think you need to use subquery instead. I have updated my answer with subquery and NOT IN operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider a correlated subquery instead of LEFT JOINs:

```
SELECT v.ID, 
       v.NameVeranstaltung, 
       v.Datum, 
       v.Uhrzeit, 
       v.Anzahl, 
       v.Beschreibung, 
       v.Enabled, 
       (select Count(t.FK_eventID) from  Teilnehmer AS t where t.FK_eventID = v.ID) as t.FK_eventID 
FROM   Veranstaltung AS v 
WHERE  v.Enabled = 1 
HAVING t_FK_eventID < v.Anzahl
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the query, you have no need to reference the `Users` table.  So, I think you want this `FROM` clause:

```
FROM Veranstaltung v LEFT JOIN
     Teilnehmer t 
     ON t.FK_eventID = v.ID AND
        t.FK_userID = 17
```

I would write the entire query as:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.NameVeranstaltung, v.Datum, v.Uhrzeit, 
       v.Anzahl, v.Beschreibung, v.Enabled, 
       Count(t.FK_eventID) 
FROM Veranstaltung v LEFT JOIN
     Teilnehmer t 
     ON t.FK_eventID = v.ID AND t.FK_userID = 17 
WHERE v.Enabled = 1 
GROUP BY v.ID, v.NameVeranstaltung, v.Datum, v.Uhrzeit, 
        v.Anzahl, v.Beschreibung, v.Enabled 
HAVING Count(t.FK_eventID) < v.Anzahl
```

Comment: Thanks for your query
But the problem is, I want to show all events which the user doesn't sign up to. With this query it shows me all events (which the user sign up to and which not)